# BigQuery load_table_from_storage won't recognize uri

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I'm running into the following error when trying to load a table from google cloud storage:
BadRequest: 400 Load configuration must specify at least one source URI (POST https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/fansidata/jobs)

Meanwhile my uri is valid (ie: i can see it in the gcs web app)

```
uris = ['gs://my-bucket-name/datastore_backup_analytics_2016_12_21_2_User/1569751766512529035929A5AA9742/output-0']

job_name = 'Load_User' 
destinationTable = dataset.table('Transfer')
job = bigquery_client.load_table_from_storage(job_name, destinationTable, uris)            
job.begin()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could be wrong, but it looks like `load_table_from_storage` in the Python API expects a single string for the third argument as opposed to a list. If you want to match multiple files, you can use a `*` at the end. For example,

```
uri = 'gs://my-bucket-name/datastore_backup_analytics_2016_12_21_2_User/1569751766512529035929A5AA9742/output-*']

job_name = 'Load_User' 
destinationTable = dataset.table('Transfer')
job = bigquery_client.load_table_from_storage(job_name, destinationTable, uri)            
job.begin()
```

Comment: That was exactly it thank you. The sequence of string lead me to believe it needed a list of strings. https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/stable/bigquery-client.html

Comment: I was confused about that too. I think that [this](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/issues) is the place to report issues with the API documentation, although it might require a Github login. I found an example of the correct usage [here](http://gcloud-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/bigquery-usage.html#inserting-data-asynchronous). In any case, I'm glad that you got it working!

Comment: I hit the same issue. Thanks for helping me resolve it. I went ahead and filed a github issue on the documentation: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/issues/3482

Answer (score 1):

[`Client.load_table_from_storage`](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/stable/bigquery-client.html#google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.load_table_from_storage) takes *one or more* source URIs (that is what `*soure_uris` means in python).  E.g.:

```
job = client.load_table_from_storage(
    'load-job-123', my_table_object,
    'gs://my-bucket-name/table_one',
    'gs://my-bucket-name/table_two')
```